# Use colon to open goto line dialog with amVim extension

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode with the amVim extension. I want to be able to use `:` to jump to a specific line, like normal vim works, instead of having another key.

I've set up my keybinding like this:

`{
    "key": "shift+;",
    "command": "workbench.action.gotoLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && amVim.mode == 'NORMAL'"
}`

When I am in NORMAL mode, it works perfectly. However, when I am in INSERT mode and type a colon, one appears in the editor (like expected) but the Goto Line dialog *also* opens.

I don't understand why, since my context shouldn't match while in INSERT mode.

Any suggestions on how to update my `when` context to get this working like I want?

Answer (score 0):

`:<line-number>` is actually just a range without a command. In normal Vi/Vim this jumps to the the line the range describes. However according to [amVim](https://github.com/aioutecism/amVim-for-VSCode) own documentation the plugin does not support ex-commands nor do they support custom mappings. This means your keyboard binding will probably not work correctly without some sort of support from amVim. However you can use the `G` motion with a count, e.g. `{count}G` to go to line number `{count}`.

Comment: Right, it's not going to work exactly like vim, but I don't want to retrain my muscle memory. What I don't understand is why vscode both inserts a colon and opens the go-to line window in INSERT mode. It seems that based on the context, the command shouldn't run at all.